# Is there a way to change the weather? Xbox 360

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is there a way to change the weather in Xbox 360 minecraft?

I like working with the sound of the rain and seeing the rain

but it doesn't happen often?

anyway to force a change?

Either using an in-game element or using a program to edit the xbox 360 minecraft save?